# Assoiciate paypal payments with the payer

Tags: php, html, paypal

So in my website I have in-game features which you can buy
I have a miniature store made and paypal buy now buttons included
What is the best and most secure way of automatically giving users there in-game bonus. When they have paid through paypal you have an option to put in a link when the payment is successful and i could have a form so when they are on that link it adds there bonuses but it also means anyone could just go to that link and get the bonuses for free.

Comment: you tie the payment gateway response, to the users account.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options (this sounds like Payments Basic)

1. Have them enter their PayPal account email address into their game account profile. When you get your IPN you match those up and issue the bonus
2. Add the `custom` field to your [HTML buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/). Associate that value to their user profile in your database. When you get your IPN, match the `custom` field up and issue the bonus

Comment: Problem with that is people might not have a paypal account and might only be using a debit card through paypal

Comment: Users can still pay via credit card using Payments Standard. Sorry if that wasn't clear.